# Is (string.length, 0) is a valid range for string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsstring

`NSString` methods like `-substringWithRange:` and `-rangeOfString:options:range:` state that:

> Important: Raises an NSRangeException if any part of aRange lies
>   beyond the end of the string.

It seems to me that range (string.length, 0) is *beyond* the end of string. However, `[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(string.length, 0)]` does not raise `NSRangeException` but returns an empty string. So I'm uncertain whether (string.length, 0) is a valid range.

In comparison, both `[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(string.length + 1, 0)]` and `[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(string.length, 1)]` will raise NSRangeException. But they are very clearly beyond the end while (string.length, 0) seems a critical point.

Answer (score 5):

It may be a matter of semantics but I would say (length, 0) is *at* the end of string, not *beyond* it. Of course (length, 1) would be beyond the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of having a `0` length in a range (when in context of a string) as the cursor's position if it were something like a text field or a text view. So a range of `(string.length, 0)` would be equivalent to setting the text cursor position at the very end of the string.